# PHP getting the days for a particular week

Tags: php

I'm trying to get entries from the database for this week, if i'm currently in the middle of the week I only want to get entries from the days in the week past and today.

Is their a standard way to do this? The only thing I can think of is:

using date "D" to get a "TUS" then saying if TUS; period of current week is 2 (MON and TUS)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
w   Numeric representation of the day of the week   0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
```

or

```
N   ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(database_timestamp)=YEAR('2016-03-19') AND WEEK(database_timestamp)=WEEK('2016-03-19') AND WEEKDAY(database_timestamp)<=WEEKDAY('2016-03-19');
```

Place your own date in place of '2016-03-19'.
This searches entries that are the same year and week as inputted date and that are the same or ealier weekdays.

You should clarify whether you want to GET ENTRIES FROM DATABASE or PARSE THEM IN PHP. This solution is database level. When using proper indexes it should be faster than parsing everything in PHP.